# Converting Vue slot code to React slot code - having trouble with passing data

Tags: reactjs, vue.js

https://codepen.io/mic1/project/editor/ANwjrN

skeleton Vue code ...

```
<SiteHeader>
  <Dropdown>
    <template id="trigger" #trigger="{ hasFocus, isOpen }">
      <span class="block":class="[(hasFocus || isOpen) ? 'border-white']"></span>
    </template>
    <template id="dropdown" #dropdown>
      <div></div>
    </template>
  </Dropdown>
</SiteHeader>

<Dropdown>
  <slot name="trigger" :hasFocus="buttonHasFocus" :isOpen="isOpen"></slot>
  <slot name="dropdown"></slot>

</Dropdown>
```

In the pen I am trying to work out how to get the Dropdown data into Trigger without the complexity (my perception) of render props. I remember reading somewhere that it can be done with hooks, but does that mean useContext and Provider wrapping - which also seems overkill?

Answer (score 1):

I think you would have to use render props method to pass data and incapsulate it in the parent component.
ex: in your Dropdown component

```
const DropDown = ({children}) => {
  const [buttonHasFocus, setButtonHasFocus] = useState(false);
  const [isOpen, setisOpen] = useState(false);
  
  return (
      <div>
        DropDown1
          {{children(buttonHasFocus, isOpen)}}     
      </div>
  )
};
```

and then just use it as following

```
<DropDown>
  {(hasFocus, isOpen) => (
    <>
      <Trigger hasFocus={hasFocus} isOpen={isOpen} />
      <Drop hasFocus={hasFocus} isOpen={isOpen} />
    </>
  )}
</ DropDown>
```

now any change in the passed state inside of the Dropdown component would reflect immediately on the Trigger and Drop components.